# Node express POST Json document invalid json

Tags: node.js, express

I want to send a json document to a POST link route, on the backend, my API parses the json body with the bodyparser and inserts the document into a MongoDB Collection, however I always get "invalid json". When I am using w-xxx-urlencode and pass the fields with urlencode, it works normally. The json document should be valid itself:

```
{"_id": "5afa7fcb01b8c6e5a83aa8f6", "Timestamp":"2020-01-01T09:01:55.128Z","PB":9191,"pot":0,"nP":4343,"L":3333,"Lze":4444,"p":5555,"ne":66666666,"Pr":7777}
```

I get the error:

```
Error: invalid json
    at error (C:\Users\U500405\git\Backend_node.js-Server\node_modules\body-parser\index.js:97:13)
    at C:\Users\U500405\git\Backend_node.js-Server\node_modules\body-parser\index.js:50:63
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\U500405\git\Backend_node.js-Server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:119:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

When I am leaving out the first "_id" field,I get the error:

```
POST /link/err 400 2.672 ms - 724
SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\U500405\git\Backend_node.js-Server\node_modules\body-parser\index.js:52:25
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\U500405\git\Backend_node.js-Server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:119:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

in the app.js module, I initialised to use Json bodyparser:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

My function to create the parsed json data and save in MongoDB is:

```
exports.create_an_FA= function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)   
    var fa = new FA(req.body);      

    //SAVE the new instance
    fa.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(400);
            res.send(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Instanz FA in Datenbank erzeugt!");
        res.status(200);
        res.json({ message: 'FA-Instance created in datbase!' });
    }
    });             
};
```

Why do I get the error no valid JSON data? it should switch automatically between json bodyparser x-www-urlencode and json(), depending on the body format right?

Edit:
I used the curl command to send post data as following:

```
curl -d "{\"Timestamp\":"\2020-01-01T09:01:55.128Z\","\PrognostizierterBetriebswert\":9191,"\posFlexPot\":0,"\negFlexPot\":4343,"\Leistungsuntergrenze\":3333,"\Leistungsobergrenze\":4444,"\posGesEnergie\":5555,"\negGesEnergie\":66666666,"\Preissignal\":7777}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:5000/DNZ/FA
```

and I get:
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application

I tried without the escaping "\" character but then I get undefined or an empty document returned...

Comment: Comment out both body parser entries and add a `console.log(req.body)` in your request handler, then include the "exact" content returned in your question. Don't embellish on it and simply show it as it appears. If you are sending this JSON from a source, then it might help to show how the request is being constructed and the payload is actually valid. The string in the question parses fine, but if you get errors then the actual content is something different.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50489545/edit) with details instead of putting them in comments. Comments should only be used by you as the "asker" to notify people asking for clarificaion or changes of those things being added to your question. The `curl` command looks wrong from here, but it would be much clearer presented within your post.